# chartjs-plugin-autocolors with pie charts

Tags: reactjs, charts, plugins, material-ui, chart.js

I use the chart.js library on my website because it has a pie chart. I want each circular article to have a different color, but I don't want to create the colors manually, I want to generate them with the help of chartjs-plugin-autocolors. But it doesn't create the colors, instead all circles are black. What have I done wrong?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Pie } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import autocolors from 'chartjs-plugin-autocolors';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';


const VendorPie = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [vendors, setVendors] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:1234/contracts/countVendorContract')
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((apiData) => {
            setData(apiData);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Hiba történt:', error);
          });

          fetch('http://localhost:1234/vendors/allVendors')
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((vendorData) => {
            setVendors(vendorData);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Hiba történt a vendor nevek lekérdezésekor:', error);
          });
      }, []);
    
      const chartData = {
        labels: data.map((item) => {
            const vendor = vendors.find((v) => v.id === item.contracted_vendor_id);
            return vendor ? vendor.name : item.contracted_vendor_id.toString();
          }),
        datasets: [{
          label: '',
          data: data.map((item) => item.darab),
          hoverOffset: 4
        }]
      };


    const chartOptions = {
      
        cutout: 70,
        plugins: {
          autocolors: {
            enabled: true,
            count: 6,
          },
        },
      };

    return (
        <Pie data={chartData} options={chartOptions} id="pie-chart" />
    );
};

export default VendorPie;
```

I installed chart.js and chartjs-plugin-autocolors

Comment: Have you [registered](https://github.com/kurkle/chartjs-plugin-autocolors#registering) the plugin?

Comment: Yes, couldn't everything be the same color because you get the data from an API call and not in an array?

Comment: If the data is rendered properly, the plugin should also work. Note also that you should explicitly set the `mode: "data"`